# What is precise definition Little-o ? :$f(x)=o(g(x)) \ \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ x \to c$

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, definition

What is precise definition Little-o ?
My definition :

> let $f :A \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g :B \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and also $c$ is an cluster point of $A,B$ and
>
> We say that:
> $$f(x)=o(g(x)) \ \ \ \ \text{as} \ \ \ x \to c$$
> if for any $ε > 0$  there exists a neighborhood $U_{\epsilon}$ of $c$ such that
> $$|f(x)| \leq \epsilon |g(x)| \ \ : \forall x \in ( A \cap B \cap U_{\epsilon} )$$
> Is It precise definition ?

Comment: The usual definition is: $f \in o(g)$ as $x \rightarrow c$ iff $\lim_{x \rightarrow c} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$. A very basic reference is http://kisonecat.com/teaching/2009/ibl-analysis/little-oh.pdf

Comment: It is indeed. If $g(x)\ne 0$ in a small neighbourhood of $c$, except perhaps in $c$, it is equivalent to the simpler condition  $\;\lim_{x\to c}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.